# Thunderbird - don't jump to next email after archiving/deleting

Tags: email, thunderbird

I'm sure I'm just blind but I cannot seem to find the right option.

My desired behaviour of Thunderbird would be: I'm in the main view (where all emails are displayed), doubleclick on an email which opens in a new tab, archive that email and then the main view is displayed again. It works exactly like this on another computer I have.

What Thunderbird does instead on this computer is to jump to the next email after archiving it, still remaining in the tab view. Can I stop Thunderbird from doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option is "Close message window/tab on move or delete".

In current Thunderbird versions, the setting can be found at *General* → *Reading & Display*.

[image: Screenshot of Thunderbird's preferences page, with the checkbox in question.]

The corresponding prefs.js or about:config setting is:

```javascript
user_pref("mail.close_message_window.on_delete", true);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that was the solution!